# Cannot kick chat members using python telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to implement self-kick command using "context.bot.kick_chat_member"
However, it gives error:
AttributeError: 'ExtBot' object has no attribute 'kick_chat_member'

Here is my  code:

```
async def Z(update, context):
    await context.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, user_id=update.effective_user.id, timeout=int(time.time() + 86400)) # expiry after 24h

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(callback_query_handler))
    
    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("image", image)],
        states={
            GENDER: [MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^(Art|Anime|Hent)$"), gender)],
            PHOTO: [MessageHandler(filters.PHOTO, photo), CommandHandler("skip", skip_photo)],
            BIO: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, bio)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )

    application.add_handler(conv_handler)

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('Z', Z))
   
    application.run_polling()
```

To note: other context.bot commands are working, for exampe:

```
await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= str(update.effective_user.first_name) + ", hello")
await context.bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, message_id=messages[i])
```

I was trying
context.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, user_id=update.effective_user.id, timeout=int(time.time() + 86400))

That did not work, I expect someone suggest which method to use to make bot kick members or how to make context.bot.kick_chat_member work.

Answer (score 1):

This method is not used in the [library version 20+](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html).

> Changed in version 20.0:
>
> Removed the deprecated methods kick_chat_member, kickChatMember, get_chat_members_count and getChatMembersCount.

Try it this way (you can see the arguments [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.chat.html#telegram.Chat.ban_member)):

```
await update.chat_member.chat.ban_member(user_id=user_id)
```

Comment: this chat is very slow response, already solved myself